# boolean value not update in Call Receiver

Tags: java, android

I have call receiver which I want to display dialog on incoming call only. For that I have created a global Boolean variable and trying to changes its value to true in ringing state. But when call disconnects, code always picks default value of Boolean not the updated value given in ringing state. The variable is num. Why it always give false value though its value getting true in ringing state only. Here is the code:

```
public class phonerece extends BroadcastReceiver{
private Boolean num = false;

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
//some task here
                     }
        } else if (extraState != null) {
            if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
//task            

            } else if (extraState
                    .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                       if (num) {
                        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
//call dialog                        }
                    }

                } else if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {


                          if (checknumber() != null) {
                        Log.e("Nummber", "found");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Number", "Not Found");
                        num = true;
                                                }


                }


            }
        }



    public String checknumber() {

        String res = null;
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
            Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) { // cursor not null means number is found contactsTable
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {   // so now find the contact Name
                    res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        /* Ignore */
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use static variables (private static num = false) or save your variable in SharedPreferences (it's better), because BroadcastReceivers are not saved between broadcasts. Every broadcast will create a new instance of the BroadcastReceiver, at least if registered automatically via the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

(Your code snippet looks broken, the `num` variable is missing its type? This answer assumes its type is `boolean`.)

This sounds like a multithreading problem. Threads in java may cache values of variables, because synchronizing through the main memory is more expensive. You can force the synchronization by flagging the field in question as `volatile`. This keyword is explained [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml).

When a field is flagged as `volatile`, Threads may not cache its value, and all modifications to the variable become visible to all other Threads.

```
private volatile boolean num = false;
```

Comment: still getting false value instead of true after making it volatile.

Comment: @Panache, too bad... :/ while debugging, you can have the debugger watch the value of the variable and break code execution whenever the value is changed (or accessed even). That way, you might be able to catch if, when and who changes the value (back) or if it is changed in the first place - maybe the wrong instance is changed?

Comment: I did that way..but value is changed first to true but never picked by idle state later.